# Which sequence settings in Adobe Premiere for a YouTube video

Tags: premiere, youtube

I have a series of photos 3840x2880 which I want to crop to make a 1080 timelapse video to be uploaded to YouTube.

Which sequence setting in Adobe Premiere CS6 I should use for YouTube videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are presets for Youtube specifically already in Adobe Media Encoder.  I would suggest using one of them.  You can also find the technical recommendations from Youtube on how to encode the videos [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en), however I believe the presets already conform to these recommendations.

Comment: Isn't Media Encoder used to "recode" existing videos? What I was asking is a step before, what sequence settings to choose before I even import my time lapse photos.

Comment: @6bytes - there are two possible questions here, the one I interpreted you asking is how do you export a sequence you have in Premiere for Youtube.  You do that through using Adobe Media Encoder and the Youtube preset (you choose external rendering in Premiere and it will automatically add it to Adobe Media Encoder for you or you can add the project to a Media Encoder queue from Media Encoder itself as well.)  Media encoder can actually be used as an external batch render engine for most of the Adobe software.  I normally run my renders in encoder to batch them up and use nested projects.

Comment: The other question would be how do you import an image sequence as a source clip in Premiere and this has nothing to do with the final desired output.  You simply make sure that you have an incrementing value on the end of a common file name and then do an import of the images and be sure to choose the Image Sequence checkbox so that it brings it in as a video source clip.